# Configure multiple SSL certificates for a single domain in Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, keystore

A year ago I have bought an SSL certificate for the `wxyz.com` domain.

With some researches, I have created an `sslKeyStore.p12` and added my certificate with `Alias=wxyz` in it.

Then I added that keyStore to the root of my project.

Also I have configured my Spring-Boot application with the following variables:

```
server.port=443
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=myPass
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=wxyz
```

Now after a year my certificate will expire soon, so I have bought another certificate and added the new certificate to the keystore with `Alias=wxyz2`.

But the question is: How can I configure my Spring-Boot application so that it works with both certificates at the same time?

In my configuration file, I can only define one     `server.ssl.keyAlias`

Is it possible to define both of the following variables at the same time?

```
server.ssl.keyAlias=wxyz
server.ssl.keyAlias=wxyz2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need both? The new one should be active already, so just replace the certificate.

Comment: @Andreas because my android clients does not have the new certificate keys, and we need to release new version of app that contains the new certificate info too!!!

Comment: But the client can easily have both installed at the same time, so get that deployed, and when all the clients are ready, switch over the server to use the new one.

Comment: @Andreas this way i need to force users to update their application quickly, i want that they update application over the next month and after that i force them to update!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not possible by design. It is not the way that SSL is intended to work - you cannot sign your HTTP responses with two keys concurrently.

The best option I see here is - as Andreas mentioned in the comments - to deploy a client app that accepts both certificates and change your server to use the new certificate on the day the old one expires. When some clients won‘t have updated on that day, there‘s nothing you can do but implementing a better software design in the future ;)

For the future you should consider switching to an SSL infrastructure that is wildly accepted by default and don‘t rely on proprietary SSL certificates. Have a look at [Let‘s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), it issues certificates for free that are accepted on most platforms that you will encounter today.

Comment: thanks for your help dude!
you are right and we are using SSL in a dirty way.
anyway you helped me to find clues for reporting to manager, Good Luck :)